# jQuery choose children of e.target

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, target

I have jQuery code that toggle class while I clicking on list element. 
*It's okay if you click on list area*... 
But when you click on `span` element, which has text "Element1", it is not working.

1. I want use this jQuery function to only elements that have another
   `ul` as a child (**Element1**).
2. I don't want to close dropdown menu by clicking any child `ul`
   elements.

```js
$(".sidebar>ul>li").has("ul").click(
  function(e) {
    if ((e.target == this)) {
      $(this).children("ul").toggleClass("toggle");
    }
  }
);
```

```css
  
.sidebar ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
.sidebar ul li ul.toggle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <span>Element1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Subelement1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Element2</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Fyi according to the [html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) li elements are only valid as a list item inside a ul or ol element.

Comment: 1. Please make an effort and at least present code snippets that can actually be run, and don't throw syntax errors. 2. Remove the check completely, it's nonsense. `$(this).children("ul").toggleClass("toggle")` as the only line in the handler function, without any ifs around it, does the job.

Comment: It does not well. I want to use this handler function when I click on li and span element. If you remove check you will toggleClass by clicking any child elements...

Comment: Then you should provide the minimal required code within your question, @CBroe comment is correct concerning the code you provided. Please read how to creat a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can achieve this:

> Please note that, as **@ste2425** stated in his comment, "*`according to the html5 spec li elements are only valid as a list item inside a ul or ol element.`*" so you should consider wrapping the outer **`li`** elements in an **`ul`**, or **`ol`**, tag.

[**jsFiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9z6rycg/)

```js
var sidebarItems = $(".sidebar>li");

sidebarItems.on('click', function(e) {
  var $th = $(this),
    subList = $(this).children("ul");

  // collapse other sub-ul by removing the class "open"
  sidebarItems.not($(this)).children('ul').removeClass('open');
  
  // check if the clicked element is a child of the a sub-ul which
  // has class open, if NOT we toggle the "open" class, note that
  // we use $(e.target) to convert the target into a jQuery object
  if (!$(e.target).parents('ul').hasClass('open')) {
    subList.toggleClass('open');
  } else {
    // just for demonstration purposes
    console.log('you clicked ' + $(e.target).text());
  }
});
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; font-weight:bold; }
li ul { display: none; }
li ul.open { display: block; }
li ul.open li{ font-weight:normal; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <span>Element 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Element 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Element 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 3.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

---

Another way to do this is using CSS, instead of the `span` elements we use "*invisible*" checkboxes with its `label` elements. and we use this CSS to open the sub `ul` which is a sibling of the relative checkbox:

```
li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul{ display: block; }
```

We still need JavaScript just in order to "uncheck" other checkboxes

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9z6rycg/1/)

```js
var items = $('.sidebar input[type="checkbox"]');
items.on('click', function(){
  items.not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```css
.sidebar li, li>label{ cursor: pointer; }
li>label{ font-weight:bold; }
.sidebar li ul{ display: none; }
.sidebar li input[type="checkbox"]{ display:none; }
.sidebar li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <input id="item1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item1">Element 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 1.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item2">Element 2</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item3">Element 3</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Sub element 3.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Sub element 3.2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item4" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item4">Element 4</label>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) of event instead of `e.target` to get parent `ul` element of a clicked `span`. And use [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
(".sidebar>ul>li").has("ul").click( function(e) { 
   $(this).children("ul").toggleClass("toggle"); 
})
.children("ul").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```